# gnu file tree...is this advisable to beginners?

Tags: unix, gnu

I am in academics, where most of the coding is done in `fortran`, `C(++`) (and little bit of `python`). My question is about projects of 2-3k lines of code using fortran.

In gnu's code, we generally see a very standard set of directories, eg `src`, `doc` etc and files like `README`, `ChangeLog` etc (I have not found anything that says these are standard directory, so, I assume them as good practice).

Now, for teaching new students (undergrads taking their 1st coding course), is it advisable to introduce them to this "standard" tree with the exact names? I have not seen many projects in academic world follow this.

So, for the beginners,  what is better?

Comment: It comes all together when using makefiles, automake, doing packaging, versioning, document generation, IDE usage and so on. Maybe let an IDE make a "standard" project and use that as template.

Comment: Yes...thats true. Actually, I have already decided to teach them autotools (inspite of the negative remarks about it). My logic here is to let them know one....they may wish to migrate to other (if they stay in coding), but to begin, its better to have a widely available and widely used tool, and bit of my personal preference. So, I opt for gnu-autotools over cmake (they may curse me later in there life).

Answer (score 2):

These are not standards in the sense of "standardised by some organization", but best practices ("coding conventions") entered in common use *many* years ago. So I think is good to introduce students to these practices if they will have to not only write, but also install and use software already made by others.